How do I connect a 24VAC doorbell transformer to a smart thermostat to power it?
The only wires present in the existing setup are R (which is tied to Rc), W, Y, and G. Is it even possible to hook up the 24VAC doorbell transformer I have to the terminal to power it?
The thermostat, if it helps, is an Amazon model. The old one is a Honeywell mechanical one with absolutely no electronics inside it; it uses a bimetallic strip and a mechanical lever for control.
This is an apartment, so I have absolutely zero access to the furnace, and maintenance won't help me for liability reasons.


I'm not referring to any hardware that's inside the wall. The transformer that I'm referring to is something that plugs into one of the outlets in the wall, and it has two output wires, that output 24 volts ac. There is no doorbell, that's just what's on the label of the wall adapter. I'm trying to power a smart thermostat.

You could power the Smart thermostat from the doorbell transformer.
To do that use the secondary side (24 volt Output) NOT the 120 V input from the transformer and connect it to the R and C on thermostat.
Which in your case would mean you need a new cable from the transformer to the thermostat.
Depending on the VA output of the doorbell transformer, you might overload it. You might need to upgrade the doorbell transformer to 50 VA.

The transformer is just a wall adapter that plugs into an outlet, and the output is just two stranded wires. The output voltage of the transformer exactly matches the input voltage of the thermostat, and the output current maximum is greater than the input spec.

@MattFerrie great so you can use it than

I actually just tried to hook it up the way I said yesterday, and it refused to power on. I guess I'm figuring out how to return it and getting a Google Nest instead

I figured out the problem. this whole time I've been trying to use a 24 volt DC power supply as though it's an AC power supply.

@MattFerrie so you had a 24 V DC power supply :)

Yep, I did have a DC power supply. Even if I did have an AC power supply it would not have worked because the power coming in from the wall would have conflicted with the power coming from the furnace. Pretty much the only way around this would be to install a dumb digital thermostat with physical buttons that runs on batteries.
